# What is だって when it's at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, register, copula, て-form, ellipsis

I have read several definitions of だって but none of them seem to make sense when I see it at the beginning of a sentence and I read the context. I saw one example Japanese sentence and in the English translation だって wasn't translated into anything.

So what is だって when it's at the beginning of a sentence?

Answer (score 8):

Well, since I have no examples to go off of, I'll guess at which type of scenario you're thinking of.  It can mean like "But" or "Well (then)" in a kind of defensive sort of way.  Usually giving a reason for some action.  Like なぜかというと.  Ex:

> お皿{さら}のものはみんな食{た}べなさい　→　Eat everything on your plate.
>   だってお腹{なか}が一杯{いっぱい}なんだもん　→　But I'm full!

Comment: Can it mean "because?"

Comment: Perhaps, but the most common way I see だって translations go wrong is using "because" when it's not appropriate. だって is used to indicate that you're providing (or implying that you have) personal thoughts/reasons justifying your behaviour/statements. It implores the other person to agree with your logic. "Because" has much more of a sense of completely firm reasoning that doesn't admit discussion. When it seems that "because" applies, "I mean / after all" is probably more fitting. (I'd advise you to post some example sentences if you want more clarification.)

Comment: @languagehacker: why would you think it could mean "because"?  If "because" there is, then in "もん" it is, not in "だって".

Comment: Is it similar to だから?

Comment: @karl: no.  1) You don't start a sentence with だから (except in Sendai, maybe).  2) Standard Japanese for だから is "because".  We (I) just said that だって is *not* "because".

Comment: I was thinking of how だから gets used in anime. It often seems like an interjection, or like it would be better translated "Like I said" or something like that.

Comment: I've often heard だから beginning a sentence, meaning either "Like I said ..." or "So ...", but I really don't see how that can be compared to だって (other than that they're both prone to being mistranslated).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: that's quite informal, probably 100% spoken, and there's an omission of all that was said before.  As for the meaning, just like Hyperworm wrote.

Comment: [お皿さらのものはみんな食たべなさい] This sentence is EXTREMELY suspicious :)

Comment: @ 龚元程 - I don't know why you think so.  But if you don't believe me, take it up with [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02602700), because that's where I got the example from.

Comment: @istraci: Not nearly native, and someone correct me if I'm wrong, but... a) Why is the food the topic of  an imperative sentence? Actually, I don't think I've ever seen a topic marker in an imperative sentence. Maybe it could be a contrastive は, but what does it contrast with? Things that fell off the plate? b) Can you use みんな for non-people? It reads more like telling everyone to eat what's on the plates, and not telling one person to eat everything on the plate.

Comment: @Amadan - You should post this question as a separate topic.  I think it's great and worthy of discussion.  But continuing that discussion here will just leave it buried and not useful for others.

Answer (score 5):

だって (at the beginning of a sentence!) is always followed by:

- reason, pretext (because, ...etc.)
- opposition (but, ...etc.)

So it's not only 'but' or 'like I said'.

It's context dependent and it CAN be translated as because.

*(Context is an emo-schoolgirl-drama.)*

> **山崎くん**：スマイルぐらいしてよ。なんでオレともう喋らないの？
>
> *At least give me a smile. Why don't you talk to me anymore?*
>
> **リカちゃん**：だって、「りかちゃんが好きじゃない」って聞いちゃった
>
> *Because I heard you don't like me.*